# 3 equal height rows in a ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, scrollview

Here is my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/banner" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/row2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Menu 1"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkBlue"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCountMyRecipes"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnViewAll1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:text="View All"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_360"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/group1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/row2" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/row3">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Menu 2"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkBlue"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCountMyFavorites"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnViewAllFavorites"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:text="View All"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_360"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/group2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/row3" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As you can see from my layout, the outer `LinearLayout` contains 3 `RelativeLayout` which all have `layout_weight` equals to 1 and the `LinearLayout` has `weightSum` equal to 3.

However, the behavior of the current layout is: The 1st `RelativeLayout` shared very little space (around 10%) and the 2nd & 3rd `RelativeLayout` shared 45% of height.

How can I make them equally shared the height?

Comment: Why do you need to make `ScrollView` as a parent? What shoud happen with these 3 views when you scroll? Anyway, try to make `ScrollView` `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to below attributes to **ScrollView**

```
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
```

**Check layout below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/banner" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Menu 1"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_360"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCountMyRecipes"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnViewAll1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:text="View All"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_360"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/group1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/row2"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Menu 2"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_360"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCountMyFavorites"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnViewAllFavorites"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:text="View All"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_360"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/group2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/row3"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I think the reason of uneven distribution of 3 rows is due to the height of recycler items, which affects the height of the last 2 rows.

Comment: I dont think so. I am getting proper output on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Because your using scrollview you need to fill your view port to make the scroll view occupy the whole screen

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"/>
        //..... your other code here 
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks , but adding `android:fillViewport="true"` does not affect the display outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I think the reason of uneven distribution of 3 rows is due to the height of recycler items, which affects the height of the last 2 rows.